# Odoo does not find model

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm writing as custom odoo module, with some configuration that can be set by the user.
Therefore, I created a `res_config.py` containing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models, fields, api


class mymodule_configuration(models.TransientModel):
  _name = 'mymodule.config.settings'
  _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

  default_myfield = fields.Char(
    string='my description',
    required=True,
    help="mydescription",
    default_model='mymodule.config.settings',
  )
```

As a view, I created `views/resconfigview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="view_mymodule_configuration" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">mymodule configuration</field>
          <field name="model">mymodule.config.settings</field>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="mymodule configuration"
                  class="oe_form_configuration">
                <sheet>
                    <div>
                        <button string="Apply"
                                type="object"
                                name="execute"
                                class="oe_highlight" />
                        or
                        <button string="Cancel"
                                type="object"
                                name="cancel"
                                class="oe_link" />
                    </div>

                    <group string="My Settings">
                        <field name="default_myfield" />
                    </group>

[..]
```

When I install the module, the server resonds with a 500. In the logfile, I find:

```
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Konnte Modell nicht finden: mymodule.config.settings
```

Message in english: `Could not find model: mymodule.config.settings`.
So in the view, my config model is not accessible.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you add `import res_config` to your `__init__.py` ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove  `_name = 'mymodule.config.settings'` from your model, because you are inherit the existing model so no need to define new name other wise it will create new model.

And then fields you have defined in new model will not be accessible in the inherited model.

Update this line in xml.

```
 <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
```

Add one more line to the xml view after model

```
<field name="priority" eval="50" />
```

Also remove `default_model='mymodule.config.settings',`

```
default_myfield = fields.Char(string='my description',required=True,help="mydescription",)
```

You missed to inherit main view of `res.config.settings`

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="set view id here"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that leads to another exception: The "default_myfield" cannot be found. In the model, I changed the "default_model" argument to 'res.config.settings'.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to restart odoo service and update your module.

Comment: Ok, I updated the field name in the view according to your update, and restarted Odoo, but the exception is still the same.

Comment: There might be issue of sequence, see the updated answer and update you r module once again.

Comment: one more issue with field declaration I found in your code, see I have update answer for that. changes in column structure need to update module.

Comment: I really appreciate your hints! Unfortunately, that does not solve it. Please find the exception here: http://pastebin.com/Reuav90e - maybe it's helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82806/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-schneck).

Comment: See I found the issue, you missed to add inherit reference in xml, find the base view id and set in xml, I have given xml line which you need to add in xml.

Comment: I am also doing in the same way but i'm also getting the same error that "default_field does not exists".
@schneck if you resolved the issue then post the updated code.

Comment: In that case you missed to inherit the base view of the model, `<field name="inherit_id" ref="set view id here"/>`

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool still struggling and trying other approaches. Will update when I found a solution. Emipro: did not forget this, but does not help.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the issue you are facing currently.

Comment: I tried in another way but got error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335547/addition-in-general-settings-of-odoo

Answer (score -1):

make sure you import the `mymodule.config.settings` in your `__init__.py` file and also run this command to save your files

```
./odoo-bin -u your module name
```

That shoud help you solve the problem