# Addition in General Settings of Odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8

I am writing as custom Odoo module, with some configuration that can be set by the user.
I want to add some setting in
Settings -> Configuration -> General Settings

Therefore, I created a **.py** containing:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class mymodule_configuration(osv.osv_memory):
   _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

  'test_field': fields.char(
                       string='Test Field',
                       required=True,
                             )
```

**.XML**

```
<record id="custom_id" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">General Settings</field>
   <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form string="General">
         <field name="test_field"/>
      </form>
   </field>
</record>
```

It does not change the *General Settings*.

If I add the reference id like:

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="base_setup.view_general_configuration"/>
```

then I got the error

> ParseError: "ValidateError
>   Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition
>
> Error details:
>   Field `module_portal` does not exist

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Defining custom settings in Odoo**

Unfortunately, Odoo documentation doesn’t seem to include any information about adding new configuration options to Odoo. So let’s fill in the gaps.

**Defining a model**

First of all, you need to define a new model inheriting from `res.config.settings`:

```
class YourSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    _name = 'your.config.settings'
```

It’s a `TransientModel`, also known as a wizard. Do not expect it to permanently hold the values. TransientModels inherently store values on a temporary basis only. You need other means to make them permanent.

Fortunately `res.config.settings make this easy. First of all, you need to add some fields to your`TransientModel` - one for every setting option you want to define. Odoo comes with built-in support for four different kinds of settings. It distinguishes between them based on the field names.

**“Default” settings**

The value of a field named `default_foo` will be set as a default value for a field named `foo` on a model given as a `default_model` argument.

```
class YourSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    _name = 'your.config.settings'

    default_name = fields.Char(default_model='your.other.model')
```

This will make the value of `default_name` field the global default value of a field `name` in model `your.other.model`.

**“Group” settings**

Boolean fields named `group_foo` take two arguments: `group` (defaults to `base.group_user`) and `implied_group`. If the value of such a field is true, the group defined in group gain all `implied_group`’s permissions. This is exactly the same as adding a group to the `implied_ids` field on another group’s object (which as far as I know is also an undocumented feature). This is useful for controlling which groups of users have access to a feature.

```
class YourSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    _name = 'your.config.settings'

    group_kill = fields.Boolean(
        group='your.secret_agents',
        implied_group='your.licence_to_kill'
    )
```

**“Module” settings**

Boolean fields named `module_foo`, when enabled will trigger the installation of a module named `foo`.

```
class YourSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    _name = 'your.config.settings'

    # if enabled will install "spies" module
    module_spies = fields.Boolean()
```

**Other settings**

By default, the values of other fields will be discarded, but you change that by implementing your own means of saving them. Just define a method named `set_foo` (where `foo` is an arbitrary string). You can also set initial values of such fields using a `get_default_foo` method (the exact form of `foo` is once again irrelevant).

For example, if you want to use settings to control the name and phone number of a company linked to the current user:

```
class YourSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    _name = 'your.config.settings'

    company_name = fields.Char()
    company_phone = fields.Char()

    @api.model
    def get_default_company_values(self, fields):
    """
    Method argument "fields" is a list of names
    of all available fields.
    """
        company = self.env.user.company_id
        return {
            'company_name': company.name,
            'company_phone': company.phone,
        }

    @api.one
    def set_company_values(self):
        company = self.env.user.company_id
        company.name = self.company_name
        company.phone = self.company_phone
```

**Defining a view**

Then you just need to define a view for your settings. Let’s use the previous example:

```
<record id="your_configuration" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Your configuration</field>
    <field name="model">your.config.settings</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Your configuration" class="oe_form_configuration">
            <header>
                <button string="Save" type="object"
                    name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
                or
                <button string="Cancel" type="object"
                    name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
            </header>
            <group string="Company">
                <label for="id" string="Name &amp; Phone"/>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="company_name"/>
                        <field name="company_name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="company_phone"/>
                        <field name="company_phone"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="your_settings_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Your configuration</field>
    <field name="res_model">your.config.settings</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="your_configuration"/>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">inline</field>
</record>
```

and of course don’t forget to make a new entry in the settings menu:

```
<menuitem id="your_settings_menu" name="Your settings"
    parent="base.menu_config" action="your_settings_action"/>
```

Reference: http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/custom-settings-odoo.html

Answer (score 2):

You can not add fields directly to the existing view.
You should try this,

```
<record id="custom_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">General Settings</field>
    <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base_setup.view_general_configuration"/>
    <field name="priority" eval="50" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <div name="Existing div name" position="inside">
                <div name="new div name">
                    <field name="test_field" class="oe_inline" />
                    <label for="test_field"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </data>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I have updated my code.
In my actual code _name was not part of this.

Comment: I got the error :
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `module_portal` does not exist

Error context:
View `General Settings`

Comment: nothing changed after updated code again same error as above comment